# Entity Framework 5: How lazy loading works in different type of relations?

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-relationship, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Entity Framework 5, MVC 4. My `User` has these relations:

`User-Profile`: 1 to 1 relationship. (one user has one profile)

`User-Posts`: 1 to many relationship. (one user has many post)

`User-Roles`: many to many relationship (one user has many roles, a role might be assign to many users)

My question is how Lazy Loading works according to each type of these relations, and how "deep"? When I get a User from Context, what will be loaded?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check this documents:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind lazy loading is that the entity framework loads only the information that you have attempted to access.  Consider the following:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    User myUser = context.Users.First();
}
```

In this example, **only** the `User` object is loaded.  None of the related entities are retrieved from the database until they are first accessed.

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    User myUser = context.Users.First();   // User is loaded from database

    Profile myProfile = myUser.Profile;    // Associated profile is loaded
}
```

In the second example, there are **two database calls** - one to load the User, and a second to load the Profile when it is first accessed.

All three types of relationships (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many) have this same behavior: related objects are not loaded until first access.